# ChartJS beginAtZero, min, max doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I tried every possible way, every form-answer but anything works inmy code. I want yAxes begin at zero and max value is 100 but all my chart begin with other values (see pic). What can I do?

```
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                max: 100,
                min: 0
            }
        }]
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: name
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },

};
```

[image: Doesn't begin at zero]

Comment: A js fiddle will help... please add.

Answer (score 16):

key is to pass options in the Chart constructor instead of part of data

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {{ chart_data|safe }},
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

above works for me!

Comment: keep in mind, beginAtZero must be a level higher than 'ticks' in Chart 3.5.1. The code above is for Chart 2

Comment: In an obscure comment to an obscure answer we find an answer that the entire internet is missing and the minds at ChartJs have made difficult to find. And thank you.

Comment: Unreal. You're not wrong @Tom - Ringo's fix works like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

Working for version 3.2.0:

```
  var options = {
  // plugins, responsive etc...

      scales: {
          y: {  
             min: 0
             }
          },

  //tooltips specifications...
  }
```

The y-axis will start at 0:

[image: Chart rendered]

Comment: It works for me, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

@Nikolas,
 Here is the fiddle where the parameters you set works well.

https://jsfiddle.net/shemdani/zkb215up/2/

```
    var options = {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                max: 100,
                min: 0
            }
        }]
    },
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: name
    },
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
        mode: 'nearest',
        intersect: true
    },

};

var data = {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [32, 59, 36, 25, 68, 71],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options:options
});
```

Please check and see what you are doing wrong. I used the basic data from charjs documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different solutions and adding `barThickness: 25` in options worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code recently with version 4 and it worked perfectly :

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [], // SAMPLE LABELS
        datasets: [{
            data: [], // SAMPLE DATA
            label: "",
            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true, // Set this to true to start the Y-axis at 
                max: 100
            },
            x: {
                // If you want to configure the X-axis, you can do it here
            }
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: ''
        }
    }
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
```