# ChartJS v4 y Axis start from Zero

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am having an issue getting my y axis to start from 0.

I am importing ChartJS v4 as follows:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>`

And my chart script is below:

```
<script>
new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type : 'line',
    data : {
        labels : ['22:08', '22:08', '17:27', '19:39', '19:45', '19:49', '19:49', '19:49', '19:50', '19:54'],
        datasets : [
                {
                    data : [23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 25.8125, 25.8125, 25.8125, 25.8125, 25.875],
                    label : "Temperature",
                    borderColor : "#3cba9f",
                    fill : false
                }]
    },
    options : {
        scales: {
                y: { 
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                } 
            },    
        title : {
            display : true,
            text : 'Elderberry Brew Temperature Over Time'
        }
    }
});</script>
```

The documentation shows this positioning for the options and the same syntax for the scale options. :

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/

I have seen many similar questions but all for older ChartJS library versions

Any help hugely appreciated!

you can view the graph in context at:

http://mattluka.co.uk/brew

Comment: Take look at https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-options. You should use the `beginAtZero` property within the scales configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ChartJS beginAtZero, min, max doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879459/chartjs-beginatzero-min-max-doesnt-work)

Comment: @MohsenRobatjazi yes I have tried that but that does not work either unfortunately

Comment: @MohsenRobatjazi The link configuration doest work either

Comment: @MohsenRobatjazi that jsfiddle doesn't show any chart? maybe the wrong js fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255266/discussion-between-mohsen-robatjazi-and-mattluka).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this code. I hope this will help :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chart.js Example</title>
    <!-- Include Chart.js library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.0/dist/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        // Data and Chart Configuration
        new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['22:08', '22:08', '17:27', '19:39', '19:45', '19:49', '19:49', '19:49', '19:50', '19:54'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: [23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 23.5, 25.8125, 25.8125, 25.8125, 25.8125, 25.875],
                        label: "Temperature",
                        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                        fill: false
                    }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true, // Set this to true to start the Y-axis at 0
                        max: 100
                    },
                    x: {
                        // If you want to configure the X-axis, you can do it here
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Elderberry Brew Temperature Over Time'
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can certainly see its working in your snippet there. However its weirdly not on my site:

http://mattluka.so.uk/brew

if you inspect the element you can see my script is the same as yours but its just refusing to. Very weird!

Comment: You're link does not open and gets redirected to another website. Any other way I can check your problem?

Comment: sorry, maybe try http://mattluka.co.uk/brew

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of your page. You have imported an older version of library too.
Remove it and move the script tag containing the initialization and creation of the chart to end of the page

Comment: So I had further issues to fix but this was certainly the core of my issue. Many thanks Mohsen!